# PostgreSql ошибка: invalid input syntax for type double precision

Tags: postgresql

В БД PostgreSql в таблице users_table поле userId имеет тип данных BIGINT, уникальное, не пустое. Использую Npgsql 6.0.2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка в консоли:  `invalid input syntax for type double precision: "userId"` или же `недопустимый синтаксис ввода для типа двойной точности`

КОД:

```
conn.Open();
NpgsqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT @'userId' FROM users_table";
NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
while (reader.Read())
{
data.Add(new string[1]);
data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
}
reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: возможно проблема в типах данных - целочисленное и строка. попробуйте преобразить

Answer (score 0):

При названии таблиц или полей не использовать заглавные буквы. В моем случае я назвал поле `user_id`